# Regex for String contains

Tags: java, regex

I need to know whether a given string contains any of the characters `*.=,?` or `:`.  I tried (using `str.contains`):

- `[*?=:]` & also
- `[^*?=:]` & also
- `^[*?=:]`

None of them seem to work.

Could anyone let me know the regex to do it?

Answer (score 5):

`contains` does not take a regex, but a simple String, as an argument. So in your example, it will look for this exact sequence of characters in your String: `[*?=:]`

You could instead use [`String.matches`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29):

```
str.matches(".*[*.=,?:]+.*");
```

Comment: I think he wants to match commas too

Comment: Could you tell me why that + is necessary.. (".*[*.=,?:].*") seems to work for me.

Comment: @user2349990 It isn't (necessary).

Comment: The whats the purpose of using it?

Comment: @user2349990 I just typed it like that and it is functionally equivalent, but the `+` is not needed.

Answer (score 4):

`String.contains` searches for the specified sequence of characters -- it does not use a regex. Instead, use:

```
s.matches(".*[*.=,?:].*")
```

This matches any string which consists of any characters, followed by one of the characters you mentioned, followed by any characters.

Answer (score 0):

The method `java.lang.String.contains(CharSequence)` does not support regular expressions. You have to create your own little helper method.

To check if a String *contains* a Substring that matches a certain regex you can use a method like this:

```
/**
 * Checks if the given string contains a substring that matches the given
 * regex.
 */
public boolean checkStringContainsStringMatchingRegex(String pString, String pRegex) {
    return Pattern.compile(pRegex).matcher(pString).find();
}
```

Difference to `java.lang.String.matches(String)`:

- `String.matches(String)` checks if the String matches the given regex
- `checkStringContainsStringMatchingRegex(String, String)` checks if the String (first argument) *contains* a substring that matches the regex (second argument).